# Html.actionlink open site in div

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, actionlink

I am new to the entire asp .net mvc 4, so I am sorry for my silly question:)

After the user logs in, I want to make a left sidebar with links. When the user clicks on a link I want to prevent opening it in new page. Instead of this I want to open it in the same page in a different div class, that is floated next to it.

Is it possible to achieve this without using ajax or jquery etc. ? I do not want to use any of these, because I am trying to make the website as secure as possible (I am making an own banking website, silly idea I know).

```
@Html.ActionLink("Balance", "Balance", "Ebank")</li>

@Html.ActionLink("Transaction", "Transaction", "Ebank")</li>
```

I want these actions to be loaded, opened in div class="bank-content"

Comment: i guess you need to use some kind of ajaxy code for that.

Comment: You could load the div content when the user first hits the page, but hide it with css until the user clicks the link, then show it.  Obviously this approach has its downsides...

Answer (score 1):

As per the idea by Markpsmith you can have something like the following:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8" id="balance">
     @Html.Action("Balance","Ebank")
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4" id="transaction">
     @Html.Action("Transaction","Ebank")
  </div>
</div>
```

Now by default: 
You can hide them using javascript or jquery and on click of button you can show them.